# Get a custom fields value to be displayed in Woocommerce email notifications

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I used WC Field factory to generate some custom fields including a textbox called "message_to_recipient." I want to pass this to the email that goes out.

In my functions.php, I am using this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'add_order_email_instructions', 10, 2 );

function add_order_email_instructions( $order, $sent_to_admin ) {

 $custom_message = get_post_meta( $order->ID, "message_to_recipient", true );

 if ( ! $sent_to_admin ) {

 echo '<h2>You received a gift Card from '.$order->billing_first_name .' '.$order->billing_last_name.'</h2>';
 echo '<p><strong>Message:</strong> ' . $custom_message. '</p>'; 

}
```

The first echo, call to `$order->billing_first_name` etc. works fine. But the second one doesn't.

having used WC Field Factory, am I simply not using the right name, or is this the wrong hook to grab the meta data from the order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the Order ID from the **`WC_Order`** object, since WooCommerce version 3+ you should need to use `get_id()` method.

Also you should better use **`WC_Order`** methods as `get_billing_last_name()` and `get_billing_last_name()` instead…

So your code should be:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'add_order_email_instructions', 10, 2 );
function add_order_email_instructions( $order, $sent_to_admin ) {
    if ( ! $sent_to_admin ) {
        // compatibility with WC +3
        $order_id = method_exists( $order, 'get_id' ) ? $order->get_id() : $order->id;
        $first_name = method_exists( $order, 'get_billing_first_name' ) ? $order->get_billing_first_name() : $order->billing_first_name;
        $last_name = method_exists( $order, 'get_billing_last_name' ) ? $order->get_billing_last_name() : $order->billing_last_name;

        $custom_message = get_post_meta( $order_id , "message_to_recipient", true );

        echo '<h2>You received a gift Card from '. $first_name .' '. $last_name .'</h2>';

        if( ! empty($custom_message) )
            echo '<p><strong>Message:</strong> ' . $custom_message. '</p>'; 
    } 
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This should work for you now *(on any WC version since WC 2.5+)*…

---

Related thread related to Orders: [How to get WooCommerce order details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details/44708344#44708344)

Comment: Thanks. I must be using the wrong field name. he rest of this code, with updated methods, works.

Comment: I replaced the key argument in the get_post_meta function to something else and the code works, its just the key name "message_to_recipient must be wrong